# Probability of Power Rangers, please correct me if I am wrong

Tags: probability, statistics

There are five Power Rangers.  Of the five,  two are male(Red, Black) and three are female (Pink, Yellow,blue.)I randomly select two of the Power Rangers, without replacement.

(a)  What is the probability that the black Ranger is one of the two selected Power Rangers?

```
pretending that you only randomly select one power ranger, the 
probability of picking the black would just be 1/5, so if you were 
to pick another it would be 1/4 so it would be 1/5 * 1/4 = .05 so 5% chance? 
it just seems low
```

(b)  What is the probability at least one of the two selected Power Rangers is female?

```
probability that one is female is 3/5, so if you were to pick 
another power ranger at random would it be 3/5*3/4
```

(c)  Given that at least one of the two selected Power Rangers is male, what is the conditional probability the Pink Ranger is selected?

```
conditional probability, wouldnt it just be 33.3% that the pink is selected given theres only three females?
```

(d)  Are the events “the Pink Ranger is one of the two selected” and “at least one of the two selected Power Rangers is female” independent?  Explain why or why not.

```
Yes, event A effects event B.
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure your answers for a through c are incorrect. Not so sure about d but I know if statement a was correct, b would have to be also.

Comment: You're right. That is too low. There are two ways to think about this: the Pink Ranger could be the first choice OR the second choice (but not both!). You got the individual probabilities correct. "Or" means add, so we would do $\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{4}$ but this is actually an overestimate because it allows for the Pink Ranger to be chosen both times. The probability of choosing the Pink Ranger both times is $\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{20}$ as you calculated. If you subtract this, what you get is $\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{20} = \frac{2}{5}$.

Comment: Another way to think about probability is by thinking about the *opposite* event happening. In this case: what is the probability that *neither* is the Pink Ranger? Well in the first draw, 4 out of 5 are not the Pink Ranger, and then 3 out of 4 the second draw. So the probability of neither being the Pink Ranger is $\frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4} = \frac{3}{5}$. Meaning that the probability that at least one is would be $1-\frac{3}{5} = \frac{2}{5}$.

Comment: You haven't changed your profile pic in years. I remember you answered one of my questions from about 5 years ago.

Comment: @Stacker are you talking to me?

Comment: @Cameron Yes haha. but i forget what it was about, and it was on another account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the commenters have pointed out, your intuition to doubt your answer to (a) was appropriate.
$$
P(\text{selected Pink}) = P(\text{Pink selected first}) + P(\text{Not pink, then Pink}) = 1/5 + 4/5 \times 1/4 = 2/5.
$$

Then
$$
P(\text{At least } 1 \text{ female}) = 1 - P(\text{both male}) = 1 - 3/5 \times 2/4 = 1 - 3/10 = 7/10.  
$$
Next, use Bayes's Theorem:
$$
P(\text{Pink}|\text{At least 1 female}) = \frac{P(\text{Pink AND at least 1 female})}{P(\text{At least 1 female})} = \frac{P(\text{Pink})}{P(\text{At least 1 female})} = \frac{2/5}{7/10} = \frac{4}{7}. 
$$
(Can you see why the middle equality is true? This is useful in the final part!)

Finally, recall that two events $A,B$ are independent if $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$. Can you use this to give a clearer explanation for (d)?

Comment: I can't answer nearly this fast.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to directly using probabilities, Bayes' Theorem, etc., the way I personally think about these questions is first through counting. And then at the end as the last step, perform a division to get the probability. I find that this helps to avoid thinking about "first" make a selection and "second" make a different selection, and all the traps my brain could fall into when thinking that way.

With 5 people to choose 2 from, there are $\binom{5}{2}=\frac{5\cdot4}{2!}=10$ ways to just choose 2 people, regardless of one being pink or not, or whatever. These 10 possible pairs are all equally likely.

How many pairs of 2 people *do* have the pink ranger? Easy, that's just 4 since you have 4 options for who pink's partner would be.

So out of 10 equally likely possible pairs, 4 qualify. The probability is $\frac{4}{10}$.

For (b), how many pairs have one or more females? Well, how many possible pairs are all male? That's $\binom{3}{2}=\frac{3\cdot2}{2!}=3$. So $7$ of the pairs have at least one female, and the probability is $\frac{7}{10}$.

I don't want to continue laying out answers to (c) and (d). But do you see how to apply the same process to understand an answer for (c)?

Comment: The reason you did 5 x 4 for the first example is because you are picking 2 people out of the group correct? Just making sure i understand where the 4 comes from, and then you just divide that by the number of people that you pick which is 2?

Comment: The "binomial coefficient" $\binom{n}{k}$ is a tool for calculating how many subsets of size $k$ exist within a set of size $n$. It is calculated as $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{\overbrace{n(n-1)\cdots}^{\text{$k$ factors}}}{k!}$. The numerator represents how you have $n$ choices to select the first member. Then only $(n-1)$ options for the second. And so on. The denominator $k!$ represents all the ways you overcounted. The same subset could have come about with the selections made in other orders. There are $k!$ orderings of each subset of size $k$.

Comment: If you think about these details, it's not all that different from thinking about the probabilities directly. But if you internalize this interpretation of $\binom{n}{k}$ and its formula, personally I find I'm not thinking about the selection order.